# How to perform K-swap operations on an N-digit integer to get maximum possible number

Tags: algorithm

I recently went through an interview and was asked this question. Let me explain the question properly:

> Given a number M (N-digit integer) and K number of swap operations(a swap
>   operation can swap 2 digits), devise an algorithm to get the maximum
>   possible integer?
>   Examples:
>   M = 132   K = 1 output = 312
>   M = 132   K = 2 output = 321
>   M = 7899  k = 2 output = 9987

My solution ( algorithm in pseudo-code). I used a max-heap to get the maximum digit out of N-digits in each of the K-operations and then suitably swapping it.

```
for(int i = 0; i<K; i++)
{
    int max_digit_currently = GetMaxFromHeap();
    // The above function GetMaxFromHeap() pops out the maximum currently and deletes it from heap

    int index_to_swap_with = GetRightMostOccurenceOfTheDigitObtainedAbove();
    // This returns me the index of the digit obtained in the previous function  
    // .e.g If I have 436659 and K=2 given,   
    // then after K=1 I'll have 936654 and after K=2, I should have 966354 and not 963654.

    // Now, the swap part comes. Here the gotcha is, say with the same above example, I have K=3.
    // If I do GetMaxFromHeap() I'll get 6 when K=3, but I should not swap it, 
    // rather I should continue for next iteration and 
    // get GetMaxFromHeap() to give me 5 and then get 966534 from 966354.

    if (Value_at_index_to_swap == max_digit_currently)
        continue;
    else
        DoSwap();
}
```

**Time complexity: O(K*( N + log_2(N) ))**
// K-times [log_2(N) for popping out number from heap & N to get the rightmost index to swap with]

The above strategy fails in this example:
M = 8799 and K = 2
Following my strategy, I'll get M = 9798 after K=1 and M = 9978 after K=2. However, the maximum I can get is M = 9987 after K=2.

What did I miss?
**Also suggest other ways to solve the problem & ways to optimize my solution.**

Comment: Couldn't you just bucket sort the digits, map out the optimal positions, and iterate over every digit, kswapping it into an optimal location?  I'm pretty sure it's order N for N digits.

Comment: Is `K` the number of swap operations that you're permitted to perform, with each swap exchanging two digits? If so then you have "`K` swap operations", not "K-swap operations".

Comment: @Wug: I didn't exactly get your solution. Also I have updated the question, fixed a typo that could create some confusion, thanks to Steve. Can you explain your solution in the form of an answer.

Comment: @Jatin: what you've missed in the case that you fail, is that the first swap you should perform if you have 8799 and 2 swaps available is not the same as the first swap you should perform if you have 8799 but only have 1 swap available. Your approach is "greedy", meaning that it optimizes the outcome at every step, but the greedy algorithm doesn't work here.

Comment: @Jatin, a minor point about complexity:  O(K*( N + log_2(N) )) is  O(K*N)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for that. If I don't go the greedy way, how should I figure out where to swap? Can you explain an approach.

Comment: @JatinGanhotra: I've posted an answer detailing my algorithm.  Well, sort of.  I misunderstood the question in its original format.  I assumed you'd meant kswaps as analogous to a kselect, and that you had unlimited swaps.  You could probably abuse my algorithm into working for the updated question though.

Comment: You would need to index the largest values in the array, and perform swaps based on those.  Probably also possible in linear time.

Comment: @JatinGanhotra I am trying to solve the same problem. Can you guide me through whether it is solvable using the above greedy approach ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive function, which sorts the possible swap values for each (current-max) digit:

```
function swap2max(string, K) {
    // the recursion end:
    if (string.length==0 || K==0)
        return string

    m = getMaxDigit(string)
    // an array of indices of the maxdigits to swap in the string
    indices = []
    // a counter for the length of that array, to determine how many chars
    // from the front will be swapped
    len = 0
    // an array of digits to be swapped
    front = []
    // and the index of the last of those:
    right = 0
    // get those indices, in a loop with 2 conditions:
    // * just run backwards through the string, until we meet the swapped range
    // * no more swaps than left (K)
    for (i=string.length; i-->right && len<K;)
        if (m == string[i])
            // omit digits that are already in the right place
            while (right<=i && string[right] == m)
                right++
            // and when they need to be swapped
            if (i>=right)
                front.push(string[right++])
                indices.push(i)
                len++
    // sort the digits to swap with
    front.sort()
    // and swap them
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        string.setCharAt(indices[i], front[i])
    // the first len digits are the max ones
    // the rest the result of calling the function on the rest of the string
    return m.repeat(right) + swap2max(string.substr(right), K-len)
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the same as the solution I came up with. Note this is `O(N)` as long as you use a non-comparative sort for `front.sort()`, otherwise it is `O(N lg N)`.

Comment: @Bergi `swap2max("7899", 1)` returns `9898`.

Comment: @JohnKurlak: Thanks, fixed (`string[++right]` vs `string[right++]`)! I also fixed a bug when the number starts with the largest digits in the front.

Comment: @Bergi `swap2max("54448123", 3)` throws an index of out bounds exception.  Also, `swap2max("12", 2)` goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnKurlak: I could not reproduce an index of bounds exception, but I fixed the infinite recursion. And have actually tested in Python instead of writing pseudocode :-)

Comment: @Bergi The infinite recursion may have been a mistake on my behalf during my translation to Java. Could you please upload your Python code somewhere so I can give it a shot?

Comment: @JohnKurlak: [Here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/167e8540-aa63-4e18-b4d6-af385771afcb/view-source) :-)

Comment: @Bergi `swap2max("321", 1)` returns `321` instead of `312`. (I assume you have to swap `k` times.)  Also, `swap2max("876959", 3)` returns `998657` instead of `998756`.

Comment: @JohnKurlak: I did assume that you could swap at most k times - otherwise, what if `k > len(str)` or `len(str) <= 1`? @876959: Oh, darn, looks like it's not as easy as I thought. Unfortunately, the only solution that comes to my mind would be to get all permutations `front` instead of sorting it, and then just trying recursively to find a maximum.

Comment: @Bergi If `k > len(str)`, I would assume you would just keep swapping: e.g., `n=21 k=10` would just do the same swap `10` times and result in `21`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the missing part is that, after you've performed the K swaps as in the algorithm described by the OP, you're left with some numbers that you can swap between themselves. For example, for the number 87949, after the initial algorithm we would get 99748. However, after that we can swap 7 and 8 "for free", i.e. not consuming any of the K swaps. This would mean "I'd rather not swap the 7 with the second 9 but with the first".

So, to get the max number, one would perform the algorithm described by the OP and remember the numbers which were moved to the right, and the positions to which they were moved. Then, sort these numbers in decreasing order and put them in the positions from left to right.

This is something like a separation of the algorithm in two phases - in the first one, you choose which numbers should go in the front to maximize the first K positions. Then you determine the order in which you would have swapped them with the numbers whose positions they took, so that the rest of the number is maximized as well.

Not all the details are clear, and I'm not 100% sure it handles all cases correctly, so if anyone can break it - go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This is all pseudocode, but converts fairly easy to other languages.  This solution is nonrecursive and operates in linear worst case and average case time.

You are provided with the following functions:

```
function k_swap(n, k1, k2):
    temp = n[k1]
    n[k1] = n[k2]
    n[k2] = temp

int : operator[k]
    // gets or sets the kth digit of an integer

property int : magnitude
    // the number of digits in an integer
```

You could do something like the following:

```
int input = [some integer] // input value

int digitcounts[10] = {0, ...} // all zeroes
int digitpositions[10] = {0, ...) // all zeroes
bool filled[input.magnitude] = {false, ...) // all falses

for d = input[i = 0 => input.magnitude]:
    digitcounts[d]++ // count number of occurrences of each digit

digitpositions[0] = 0;
for i = 1 => input.magnitude:
    digitpositions[i] = digitpositions[i - 1] + digitcounts[i - 1] // output positions

for i = 0 => input.magnitude:
    digit = input[i]
    if filled[i] == true:
        continue
    k_swap(input, i, digitpositions[digit])
    filled[digitpositions[digit]] = true
    digitpositions[digit]++
```

I'll walk through it with the number `input = 724886771`

```
computed digitcounts:
{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0}

computed digitpositions:
{0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 9}

swap steps:
swap 0 with 0: 724886771, mark 0 visited
swap 1 with 4: 724876781, mark 4 visited
swap 2 with 5: 724778881, mark 5 visited
swap 3 with 3: 724778881, mark 3 visited
skip 4 (already visited)
skip 5 (already visited)
swap 6 with 2: 728776481, mark 2 visited
swap 7 with 1: 788776421, mark 1 visited
swap 8 with 6: 887776421, mark 6 visited

output number: 887776421
```

## Edit:

This doesn't address the question correctly.  If I have time later, I'll fix it but I don't right now.

Comment: Seems to work quite nice, but I don't see the limitation to k swaps. Also, what is `digitposition` - did you miss an "s"?

Comment: Probably.  I interpreted K-Swap differently than it was intended so the solution is a tad skewed.  I'm going to fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it (in pseudo-c -- nothing fancy), assuming a fantasy integer array is passed where each element represents one decimal digit:

```
int[] sortToMaxInt(int[] M, int K) {
    for (int i = 0; K > 0 && i < M.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (swapDec(M, i)) K--;
    }
    return M;
}

bool swapDec(int[]& M, int i) {
    /* no need to try and swap the value 9 as it is the 
     * highest possible value anyway. */
    if (M[i] == 9) return false;

    int max_dec = 0;
    int max_idx = 0;
    for (int j = i+1; j < M.size(); j++) {
        if (M[j] >= max_dec) {
            max_idx = j;
            max_dec = M[j];
        }
    }

    if (max_dec > M[i]) {
        M.swapElements(i, max_idx);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From the top of my head so if anyone spots some fatal flaw please let me know.

Edit: based on the other answers posted here, I probably grossly misunderstood the problem. Anyone care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You start with `max-number(M, N, 1, K)`.

```
max-number(M, N, pos, k)
{
    if k == 0
        return M
    max-digit = 0
    for i = pos to N
        if M[i] > max-digit
            max-digit = M[i]
    if M[pos] == max-digit
        return max-number(M, N, pos + 1, k)
    for i = (pos + 1) to N
        maxs.add(M)
        if M[i] == max-digit
            M2 = new M
            swap(M2, i, pos)
            maxs.add(max-number(M2, N, pos + 1, k - 1))
    return maxs.max()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach (It's not fool-proof, but covers the basic cases). First we'll need a function that extracts each DIGIT of an INT into a container:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::deque<int>> getDigitsOfInt(const int N)
{
    int number(N);
    std::shared_ptr<std::deque<int>> digitsQueue(new std::deque<int>());
    while (number != 0)
    {
        digitsQueue->push_front(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return digitsQueue;
}
```

You obviously want to create the inverse of this, so convert such a container back to an INT:

```
const int getIntOfDigits(const std::shared_ptr<std::deque<int>>& digitsQueue)
{
    int number(0);
    for (std::deque<int>::size_type i = 0, iMAX = digitsQueue->size(); i < iMAX; ++i)
    {
        number = number * 10 + digitsQueue->at(i);
    }
    return number;
}
```

You also will need to find the MAX_DIGIT. It would be great to use std::max_element as it returns an iterator to the maximum element of a container, but if there are more you want the last of them. So let's implement our own max algorithm:

```
int getLastMaxDigitOfN(const std::shared_ptr<std::deque<int>>& digitsQueue, int startPosition)
{
    assert(!digitsQueue->empty() && digitsQueue->size() > startPosition);
    int maxDigitPosition(0);
    int maxDigit(digitsQueue->at(startPosition));
    for (std::deque<int>::size_type i = startPosition, iMAX = digitsQueue->size(); i < iMAX; ++i)
    {
        const int currentDigit(digitsQueue->at(i));

        if (maxDigit <= currentDigit)
        {
            maxDigit = currentDigit;
            maxDigitPosition = i;
        }
    }
    return maxDigitPosition;
}
```

From here on its pretty straight what you have to do, put the right-most (last) MAX DIGITS to their places until you can swap:

```
const int solution(const int N, const int K)
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::deque<int>> digitsOfN = getDigitsOfInt(N);

    int pos(0);
    int RemainingSwaps(K);
    while (RemainingSwaps)
    {
        int lastHDPosition = getLastMaxDigitOfN(digitsOfN, pos);
        if (lastHDPosition != pos)
        {
            std::swap<int>(digitsOfN->at(lastHDPosition), digitsOfN->at(pos));

            ++pos;
            --RemainingSwaps;
        }
    }

    return getIntOfDigits(digitsOfN);
}
```

There are unhandled corner-cases but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed K = 2, but you can change the value!

#### Java code

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Solution d = new Solution();
        System.out.println(d.solve(1234));
        System.out.println(d.solve(9812));
        System.out.println(d.solve(9876));
    }
    public int solve(int number) {
        int[] array = intToArray(number);
        int[] result = solve(array, array.length-1, 2);
        return arrayToInt(result);
    }
    private int arrayToInt(int[] array) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = array.length-1 ;i >= 0; i--) {
            s = s + array[i]+"";
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    private int[] intToArray(int number){
        String s = number+"";
        int[] result = new int[s.length()];
        for(int i = 0 ;i < s.length() ;i++) {
            result[s.length()-1-i] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i)+"");
        }
        return result;
    }
    private int[] solve(int[] array, int endIndex, int num) {
        if (endIndex == 0)
            return array;
        int size = num ;
        int firstIndex = endIndex - size;
        if (firstIndex < 0)
            firstIndex = 0;
        int biggest = findBiggestIndex(array, endIndex, firstIndex);
        if (biggest!= endIndex) {
            if (endIndex-biggest==num) {
                while(num!=0) {
                    int temp = array[biggest];
                    array[biggest] = array[biggest+1];
                    array[biggest+1] = temp;
                    biggest++;
                    num--;
                }
                return array;
            }else{
                int n = endIndex-biggest;
                for (int i = 0 ;i < n;i++) {
                    int temp = array[biggest];
                    array[biggest] = array[biggest+1];
                    array[biggest+1] = temp;
                    biggest++;
                }
                return solve(array, --biggest, firstIndex);
            }
        }else{
            return solve(array, --endIndex, num);
        }
    }
    private int findBiggestIndex(int[] array, int endIndex, int firstIndex) {
        int result = firstIndex;
        int max = array[firstIndex];
        for (int i = firstIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
            if (array[i] > max){
                max = array[i];
                result = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```